# Make selection frame follow picturebox after resize

Tags: c#, .net, picturebox

I have 2 pictureboxes, one over another. One serves as a selection frame, another - as a picture holder. And now the problem: when i try to resize the main form of my program, it recalculates and resizes picture in main picturebox, but i cant understand how to make the second one follow it's prev. position.

Thats what i have, called in form1_ResizeEnd:

```
  pictureBox3.Left += this.Width - windowWIDTH;
  pictureBox3.Top += this.Height - windowHEIGHT;
```

windowWIDTH and windowHEIGHT - previous window dimensions.

It works, but with some problems - my picturebox mode is Centered, which means that the picture itself moves differently, and +5 to form width does not mean +5 to picture's left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AND while i was writing this question i found an answer myself. 
Here it is:

```
pictureBox3.Left += (this.Width - windowWIDTH)/2;
pictureBox3.Top += (this.Height - windowHEIGHT)/2;
```